# ADO.NET Entity Framework and Linq to Entities

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm confused about Linq to Entities. Is it the new name of Entity Framework or are they different things?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LINQ to Entities is really simply the standard LINQ extension methods (Where, OrderBy, etc), when used to query Entity Framework. This isn't the only option; EF can also be queried in a custom dialect of SQL - [Entity SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387145.aspx). In reality, the LINQ extension methods are used to generate Entity SQL, and then that Entity SQL is passed down to the provider.

That way, people implementing a new EF provider (since it is extensible) only have to worry about one thing for query: Entity SQL.

Of course, to *strictly* count as LINQ, you would need to use the *language* part too, i.e.

```
from product in db.Products
     where product.IsActive
     select product.Name;
```

etc - but since this boils down to extension methods anyway (on `Queryable`/`IQueryable<T>`), most people would count direct extension usage as LINQ - i.e.

```
var qry = db.Products.Where(x=>x.IsActive).Select(x=>x.Name);
```